# C++ Member Function Pointer From other class

Tags: c++, function, pointers, member, pointer-to-member

I am creating a console menu in C++ and I want to give every item in my menu a callback function, so when an item is selected, a different function is called. 
So far, I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Core
{
    public:

    void action1() {}

    void action2() {}
    //...
};

typedef void (Core::*CoreFunc)();

class Menu
{
    struct Option
    {
        Option(CoreFunc cb) : callback(cb) {}
        //some data
        CoreFunc callback;
        //some more data
    };

    vector<Option> m_options;

    public:

    Menu(Core const& core)
    {
        addOption(core.action1);
    }

    void addOption(CoreFunc callback)
    {
        m_options.push_back(Option(callback));
    }

    void execOptionX(int index)
    {
        m_options[index].callback();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Core core;

    Menu menu(core);

    menu.execOptionX(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Which is giving me this error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Menu::addOption(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

at `addOption(core.action1);`

and also

```
must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘((Menu*)this)->Menu::m_options.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<Menu::Option, std::allocator<Menu::Option> >(((std::vector<Menu::Option>::size_type)index)).Menu::Option::callback (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* ((Menu*)this)->Menu::m_options.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<Menu::Option, std::allocator<Menu::Option> >(((std::vector<Menu::Option>::size_type)index)).Menu::Option::callback) (...)’
```

when I try to call the function.

I have seen many implementation of member function pointer, but they are all used within the same class.

Why am I getting these errors?

What is the correct syntax to get this code to compile/work?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `CoreFunc` as a non-static **pointer-to-member-method**.  So you need to specify a pointer to the desired method, eg:

```
addOption(&Core::action1);
```

More importantly, you also need to provide a `Core` object instance as the `this` parameter for the callback.  You specify the object via the `.*` operator (if using an object reference) or the `->*` operator (if using an object pointer), eg:

```
void execOptionX(int index)
{
    CoreFunc callback = m_options[index].callback;
    (SomeCoreObj.*callback)();
}
```

```
void execOptionX(int index)
{
    CoreFunc callback = m_options[index].callback;
    (SomeCoreObjPtr->*callback)();
}
```

So, you need to change your `Menu` class to keep track of the `Core` object that will be passed to the callback (assuming you don't want to pass the `Core` object as a parameter to `execOptionX()`, eg:

```
class Menu
{
    struct Option
    {
        Option(CoreFunc cb) : callback(cb) {}
        //some data
        CoreFunc callback;
        //some more data
    };

    Core &m_core;
    vector<Option> m_options;

public:

    Menu(Core &core)
        : m_core(core)
    {
        addOption(&Core::action1);
    }

    void addOption(CoreFunc callback)
    {
        m_options.push_back(Option(callback));
    }

    void execOptionX(int index)
    {
        CoreFunc callback = m_options[index].callback;
        (m_core.*callback)();
    }
};
```

And of course, the `Core` object has to remain alive for the lifetime of the `Menu` (which it does in your `main()` example).

Comment: Ok, I added `Core &m_core` to my `Menu` class and corrected `addOption(&Core::action1);`. However, when I do `m_core.*callback();`, I still get the error `must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘callback (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* callback) (...)’`